# How to determine if rig was setup

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I purchased a blender character online. I trying to use it in a project. I attached an image, but noticed when I moved the foot bone the character didnot raise the legs. How do I tell if the rig was setup or am I in the wrong view.[image]   Bone 006 was moved , but on the left view the legs has not

Comment: maybe switch your object to weight paint mode to check the weight of each bone on the mesh. Anyway, if the object has been parented it should have an armature modifier.

Comment: I remove all the extran stuff and will re-rig it myself.